# User Control C# Not working

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, jquery-select2

I have one user control into C#.Inside that user control there is one dropdown for that i am using select2. to fill data to dropdown i am calling Web method. but when i run code web method is not called. 
Below is my code  :

```
SearchPinCode.ascx

<select class="form-control select2" id="pinCode">                                    
</select>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pinCode").select2({
           ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("SearchPinCode.ascx/GetPinCode") %>',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: function (params) {
                return JSON.stringify({
                    prefixText: params
                });
            },
            results: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return { results: data };
            },
            cache: true,
            tags: true
        },
        minimumInputLength: 1
    });
});
```

Web Method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] 
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetPinCode(string prefixText)
{
    string Query = string.Empty, ErrorMsg = string.Empty;
    Query = "....";
    List<string> items = new List<string>(10);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);            
        da.Fill(ds);         
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[0], Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with "GET" type of AJAX?

Comment: yes i  have also tried with GET but still not working